# Error JS Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando hacer un carrito de compras con JS y sin base de datos.
Mi problema viene a raiz de que cuando intento agregar un producto al carrito me sale el siguiente error en la consola:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contains')
> at addCarrito (productos.js:37:28)
> at HTMLDivElement. (productos.js:10:5)

Fuí a esa línea de código, pero no logro darme cuenta de el error

adjunto codigo JS Y HTML

**HTML:**

```html
 <div class="container">
 <h5>Carrito</h5>
    <hr>
    <div class="row" id="item">

        <template id="template-card">
            <div class="col-12 mb-2 cold-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="" alt="" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5>Titulo</h5>
                        <p>precio</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-dark">Añadir al carrito</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>

        <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-4" class="item">
            <div class="card">
            <img src="../Multimedia/aceite-oliva.png" alt="">
            <h3>ACEITE OLIVA EXTRA VIRGEN</h3>
            <p>$899,00</p>
            <button class="btn btn-dark"  data-id="1">AÑADIR AL CARRITO</button>
            </div>
            </div>
       
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-4" class="item">
            <div class="card">
            <img src="../Multimedia/Rutini_Merlot.jpg" alt="">
            <h3>RUTTINI MERLOT</h3>
            <p>$1850,00</p>
            <button class="btn btn-dark" data-id="5">AÑADIR AL CARRITO</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-4" class="item">
            <div class="card">
            <img src="../Multimedia/queso-gruyere.png" alt="">
            <h3>QUESO GRUYERE</h3>
            <p>$220,00</p>
            <button class="btn btn-dark" data-id="6">AÑADIR AL CARRITO</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        
</div>
</div>

</article>
```

**CODIGO JS:**

```js
const item = document.getElementById('item')
const templateCard = document.getElementById('template-card').content
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
        fetchData()
});

item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    addCarrito(e)
});

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch('../api.json')
            const data = await res.json() 
            //console.log(data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
};

const pintarCards =  data =>{
    data.forEach(producto =>{
        templateCard.queryselector('h5').textcontent = producto.title
        templateCard.queryselector('p').textcontent = producto.title
        templateCard.queryselector('img').setAttribute('src', producto.thumbnailURL)
        templateCard.queryselector('btn btn-dark').dataset.id = producto.id
        const clone = templateCard.cloneNode(true)
        fragment.appendChild(clone)
    })
    item.appendChild(fragment)
};
const addCarrito = e => {
    //console.log(e.target)
    //console.log(e.target.classlist.contains('btn-dark'))
    if (e.target.classlist.contains('btn-dark')){
        setCarrito(e.target.parentElement)
    }
    e.stopPropagation()
}
const setCarrito = objeto =>{
    console.log(objeto)
    const producto = {
        id : objeto.queryselector('.btn-dark').dataset.id,
        title: objeto.queryselector('h5').textcontent,
        precio: objeto.queryselector('p').textcontent,
        cantidad: 1 
    }
    if(carrito.hasOwnProperty(producto.id)){
        producto.cantidad = carrito[producto.id].cantidad + 1 
    }
    carrito[producto.id] = {...producto}
    console.log(carrito)
}
```

Comment: No puedes agregar elementos inexistentes al carrito. Edita la pregunta y agrega más detalles como los pasos que realizas para que te genere el error.

Comment: tienes que cambiar classlist por `classList` hay que fijarse en eses detalles..... jejejeje

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios errores. Tienes que cambiar classlist por `classList`, textcontent por `textContent`, queryselector por `querySelector` y dentro de un querySelector, h5 y tienes que poner `h3`.

También tienes que declarar globalmente carrito. `const carrito ={};`